# Why I can't see original code using source maps (uglify2)?

Tags: javascript, source-maps, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I am trying to optimize my source files with uglify-js optimizer (v2). I have this project: [test project](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/task-manager-ng)

I am using this to optimize `app.js` file:

```
uglifyjs app.js --source-map app.js.map -o app.js --source-map-root http://localhost:8080/js
```

*Note* that I *convert* original file to optimized (optimized file name = original file name). **May be this is the problem?**

After that I open app in the Chrome and I get this:
[image]

So I see message "Source map detected", I also see `//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map` with correct value. But I don't see original file code (before optimization). Why?

Also, I see another `localhost:8080` domain and `/js/app.js` in it. But it is blank.

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I misunderstand what is sourcemap? I thought it is a tool which allow me to see/debug code in production (optimized/uglified/minified etc) like I do it in sources. Am I wrong?

I also have this test project: [lets-try-es6-features](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/lets-try-es6-features). I just tried to enable source-maps here (only by adding `-s` key to the build command). Works like a charm. I can debug classes, arrow functions etc (everything like in source code). I don't see anything even close to this behaviour when I optimize my simple es5 file. Why?

Comment: `htt://localhost:8080/js` - `htt:` instead of `http:`?

Comment: Phew :) That was close :) I fixed this :) Same result :(